# Monaco Editor + Electron + Vue only renders plain text only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuejs3, monaco-editor

I imported Monaco editor into my Vue Electron project. No matter what language I try to use, it always renders as plain text in the browser. Any idea what's going on or how I can solve it?

This is how I initiated it:

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('hello-world-test'), {
    value: ['var hello = "world"'].join('\n'),
    language: 'javascript',
    minimap: {
      enabled: true,
    },
});
```

This is the element it is applied to:

```
<div id="hello-world-test" class="vh-100 text-start position-absolute end-0"></div>
```